# How can i get item from dropdown list as output twice or thrice or any number of times as user inputs through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

How can i get item from dropdown list as output twice or thrice or any number of times as user inputs through JavaScript

I am facing problem in retriving output from dropdownlist twice/thrice,etc in SVG(Scalable Vector Graphics.) with JavaScript E.g I made a dropdownlist and items are Rectagle,PolyLine and Circle(This shapes are in SVG) and my design page consists- textbox where we will fetch user input ,dropdownlist as above mentioned and 1 submit button.so when user for example typed 2 in textbox and select Rectangle from dropdownlist then ouput should be in 2 times i.e draw rectangle 2 times and if user inputs 3 then 3 Rectangles should be there,etc.please help me as soon as possiblePlease help me anyone

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Exersice3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right"> <input type="text" name="" style="width: 25%;" id="getValue"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center"> <select id="totalItems">     <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>     <option value="polyline">PolyLine</option>     <option value="circle">Circle</option>    </select> </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left"> <input type="submit" name="" value="Create" onclick="myFunction()"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      debugger;
      var uInput = document.getElementById("getValue").value;
      var totalItems = document.getElementById("totalItems").value;
      if (totalItems[1].value == "polyline") {
        for (var i = 1; i <= uInput; i++) {
          var poly = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polyline");
          poly.setAttribute("points", "20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180");
          poly.setAttribute("fill", "none");
          poly.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
          poly.setAttribute("stroke-width", 2);
          document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(poly);
        }
      } else if {
        for (var i = 1; i <= uInput; i++) {
          var circlee = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
          circlee.setAttribute("cx", 50);
          circlee.setAttribute("cy", 50);
          circlee.setAttribute("r", 40);
          circlee.setAttribute("fill", "red");
          circlee.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
          circlee.setAttribute("stroke-width", 3);
          document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(circlee);
        }
      }
    }
  </script> <svg id="mySVG">   </svg> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can show?

Comment: I would use a `select` for the shapes and an `input type="number" min="1"` for the number of shapes. In order to be able to help you I would need to see your code

Comment: @enxaneta <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>  <title>Exersice3</title>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </head> <body> <div class="container">  <div class="contai

Comment: @Bryan <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>  <title>Exersice3</title>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> </head> <body> <div class="container">  <div class="container

Comment: @Bryan sorry i am not able to give complete code

Comment: Please remove the code from the comments and update your question. There is an edit button just under the tags

Answer (score 2):

Your code as it is is not working. I've made some changes in `myFunction()` and the code works correctly **but** ...

In your code you can draw a polygon or a circle. There is no function to draw a rect.

Supposing that you want to create 2 circles, this works but you can see only one circle since the other is hidden behind the other. The same happens with the `polyline`.

Here you need to create a function to draw the circle that takes an `x`, `y` and `r` arguments. Also you would need a way to decide the new position and radius of your circle.

You would need to do the same for the `polyline`. You would need a way to decide the points for a new shape.

```js
 function myFunction() {
      debugger;
      var uInput = document.getElementById("getValue").value;
      
      var total_Items = totalItems.options[totalItems.selectedIndex].value;
      if (total_Items == "polyline") {
        for (var i = 1; i <= uInput; i++) {
          var poly = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polyline");
          poly.setAttribute("points", "20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180");
          poly.setAttribute("fill", "none");
          poly.setAttribute("stroke", "blue");
          poly.setAttribute("stroke-width", 2);
          document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(poly);
        }
      
      } else{
        for (var i = 1; i <= uInput; i++) {
          var circlee = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
          circlee.setAttribute("cx", 50);
          circlee.setAttribute("cy", 50);
          circlee.setAttribute("r", 40);
          circlee.setAttribute("fill", "red");
          circlee.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
          circlee.setAttribute("stroke-width", 3);
          document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(circlee);
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right"> 
          <input type="number" value = "1" name="" style="width: 25%;" id="getValue"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center"> 
          <select id="totalItems">
            <option value="rectangle">Rectangle</option>
            <option value="polyline">PolyLine</option>     
            <option value="circle">Circle</option>    
          </select> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left"> 
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Create" onclick="myFunction()"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <svg id="mySVG"></svg>
```